# Specifying target_link_libraries when building shared object in cmake

Tags: cmake

My project creates a shared object A that 'depends' should reference other shared objects B, C , D and E. After building the project and checking the build with the utility `ldd` I see no references to the shared objects B, C , D and E. However when I use the directive `target_link_libraries(A , B , C , D , E )` in my build the references to the shared objects appear in `A.so`. My question is two fold:

1. Is it correct to use `target_link_libraries` in this way?
2. If so, why is this use of `target_link_libraries` correct considering that I'm building a shared object where linking is at runtime.

---

**Example**:

My Frobnigator project depends on a ContinuumTransfunctioner and Transmogrifier shared objects that have already been built. My question is about whether the line `target_link_libraries(Frobnigator ${Libraries})` is necessary.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(Libraries
    ContinuumTransfunctioner
    Transmogrifier
)

set(SourceFiles
    Wrapper.cpp
    Logger.cpp
)

add_library(Frobnigator SHARED ${SourceFiles})
add_library(FrobnigatorStatic STATIC ${SourceFiles})
set_target_properties(FrobnigatorStatic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME Frobnigator)
#target_link_libraries(Frobnigator ${Libraries}) # Do I need this?
```

Comment: Considering that CMake is supposed to work cross-platform this make sense: On Windows when building a "shared library", those references are absolutely necessary, because when the dll is created all referenced libraries must be linked in.

Comment: `shared object where linking is at runtime` - **Linking** is performed at **build time**. At *runtime* (loading time) you only *resolve the linkage*. `shared object A that 'depends' should reference other shared objects B, C , D and E.` - What does it mean? What 'depends' means here? May be providing some code will make things clearer...

Comment: @Andre But I'm building on Linux. Do I need `target_link_libraries` in order to specify which shared objects A depends on? It just doesn't make sense to me (yet).

Comment: @Olumide. I am only suggesting that you use CMake, a cross-platform tool, and that CMake (and you too) must consider that your CMakeLists should without issues on Windows. And then the target_link_libraries is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tsyvarev See my edit. You make a good point about _linking at build time_.

Comment: So 'depends' means that your `Frobnigator` library *uses some functions* (or other symbols) from libraries `ContinuumTransfunctioner` and `Transmogrifier`, am I right about your intention?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes. Apologies for my wanton imprecision :)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've got a related question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343005/directing-cmake-to-link-against-shared-object-with-debug-postfix-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `target_link_libraries` even when create *SHARED* library.

While some symbol resolution is performed at *runtime* (*loading* time), there some things which should be performed at *build time* (**linking**).

The main thing is ... providing a list of libraries, which should be loading with your library. This list is "embedded" into the library file. There is no other way for **dynamic loader** to know, which other libraries should be loaded with your one.

Among other things performed at link time is:

- *Checking* that all symbols needed for your library are *actually available* in other libraries.