# Directing cmake to link against shared object with debug postfix (_d)

Tags: cmake

I've got a cmake project that pretty much looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

SET(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")

include_directories(../TransfunctionerProject)
include_directories(../TransmogrifierProject)

set(Libraries
    ContinuumTransfunctioner
    Transmogrifier
)

set(SourceFiles
    Wrapper.cpp
    Logger.cpp
)

add_library(Frobnigator SHARED ${SourceFiles})
add_library(FrobnigatorStatic STATIC ${SourceFiles})
set_target_properties(FrobnigatorStatic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME Frobnigator)
target_link_libraries(Frobnigator ${Libraries})
```

Where ContinuumTransfunctioner and Transmogrifier projects include the debug postfix directive `SET(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")` so that `libContinuumTransfunctioner_d.so` and `libTransmogrifier_d.so` both exist.

The problem is that the current project appears to be linking against the ***static*** library without the _d suffix and complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lContinuumTransfunctioner
```

Comment: can you post the output of the linking stage if you run cmake with VERBOSE=1 , it would be easier to find the solution and verify possible mistakes.

Comment: also, are you sure you configured cmake with -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ?

Comment: @TomazCanabrava Yes cmake is configured with ` -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` (BTW that's the default innit?). `make VERBOSE=1` links `-lContinuumTransfunctioner -lTransmogrifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, courtesy of the good people on the [cmake mailing list](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2017-April/065301.html):

```
# Note:
#    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_d> is called a generator expression.
#    It outputs _d if the build is debug.
#
set(Libraries
    ContinuumTransfunctioner$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_d>
    Transmogrifier$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_d>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Libraries` that you pass into the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) call are interpreted as filenames, not as target names.

This is the unfortunate fallback for that call in CMake: If you pass a random string to it, that cannot be interpreted in a meaningful way, CMake will always assume it to be *plain library name*. Sometimes this is just what you want, but the name has to be an exact match for an existing library. The whole debug postfix magic will be lost here.

What you might have wanted to do was to pass a *library target name* instead. This will trigger a much smarter handling of the dependency and would solve your problem. However, that only works if the library is a known target in the context of the `target_link_libraries` call. You can easily check this as follows:

```
if(TARGET ContinuumTransfunctioner)
    message("Library target name")
else()
    message("Plain library name")
endif()
target_link_libraries(Frobnigator ContinuumTransfunctioner)
```

So how do you get to the target name case? This depends on how your build is structured. If the library is being built as part of your CMake run, simply make sure that the corresponding `add_library` call is performed from a subdirectory that is pulled in via `add_subdirectory` from the file that performs the `target_link_libraries` call.

If the library in question is an external dependency, you need to build an [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) that carries all the relevant information where to find the library files (including any potential debug postfixes). This can be a bit cumbersome to do manually, so if you can, you might want to use CMake's [packaging mechanism](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) to generate this automatically as part of the library's build process.

Comment: @ComicsSansMS I got "Library target name". The libraries ContinuumTransfunctioner and Frobnigator are not built as part of Frobnigator. Which feature of the packaging mechanism should I be looking at specifically?

Comment: @Olumide The section about creating packages should be of particular interest, but make sure you also understand how `find_package` works in that case. Be aware though that this is a very complex topic and not for the faint of heart.